# NSInternalInconsistencyException error removing tableview cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm getting an NSInternalInconsistencyException when trying to remove a single row from my table view. The table view contains several sections, with one row per section. I'm doing the following:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:index];
                [indexPathToDelete addObject:indexPath];
[self.tableView beginUpdates];
[self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPathToDelete withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
[self.tableView endUpdates];
```

Before the update, I've updated my model (a NSArray containing one object for every row of my table view), deleting the object at `index`.

What am I doing wrong?

I've checked that I'm returning the correct number of sections after deleteing the object from the model and the table in the method `-(NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you post the assertion message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have one section per item, you also need to tell the table view that the section itself has been deleted with a call to [`deleteSections:withRowAnimation:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/deleteSections%3awithRowAnimation%3a) inside your `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` block.